Does the term 'initializer' also refer to the initialization assignment?
I was learning about the new class syntax that allows you to put the field initialization code directly in the class body. The wording of the text I'm confused by is as follows. It fully explains the new syntax:

Suppose you’re writing a class like this one, with a constructor that initializes three fields:
class Buffer {     
   constructor() {         
   this.size = 0;
   this.capacity = 4096;
   this.buffer = new Uint8Array(this.capacity);
   } 
} 

With the new instance field syntax, you could instead write:
class Buffer {     
   size = 0;
   capacity = 4096;
   buffer = new Uint8Array(this.capacity);
}

The field initialization code has moved out of the constructor and now appears directly in the class body. (That code is still run as part of the constructor, of course. If you do not define a constructor, the fields are initialized as part of the implicitly created constructor.) The this. prefixes that appeared on the lefthand side of the assignments are gone, but note that you still must use this. to refer to these fields, even on the righthand side of the initializer assignments. The advantage of initializing your instance fields in this way is that this syntax allows (but does not require) you to put the initializers up at the top of the class definition, making it clear to readers exactly what fields will hold the state of each instance. You can declare fields without an initializer by just writing the name of the field followed by a semicolon. If you do that,
the initial value of the field will be undefined.

I know this is essentially saying 'initializing your instance fields this way makes your code more readable,' however, I don't see how putting the field initializers themselves at the top of the class definition makes it clearer what field will hold each instance. I'd expect putting the FIELD INITIALIZATION CODE (the initialization assignments), instead of the field initializers, at the top of the class definition to do this; i'm confused as to whether the text was referring to the field initializers themselves or the field initialization code in the phrase "this syntax allows you to put the initializers up at the top of the class definition"
I've searched many different sources including Chatgpt, but it keeps changing what it believes 'initializers' refers to: sometimes it says it refers to the field initialization code and some other times, it says it refers to the initializers themselves.

Can you provide some syntax examples to make it clearer about what you mean by “field initialization code” vs “field initializers”

@NickParsons I've edited my question to include syntax examples.

Thanks. I'd say it's referring to both syntaxes foo; and foo = 1;, having just foo; by itself and the beginning of the class can help with readability, as a constructor may have other logic in it that isn't strictly to do with initialising instance variables, moreover, there might be some other method responsible for setting foo which the constructor calls, so it's clearer up-front what properties an object will have that way.

eg: a Rectangle class might set its dimensions by calling this.setDimensions(w, h) in the constructor, and then in that method that's where the property assignments live which do this.height = h; this.width = w;, defining height; and width; at the beginning of the class makes it easier to see that the class has a height and width property without having to dig too far into the code.

But yeah, it's a bit opinionated and depends on how you write you'd write your constructors normally on whether on initializing them up-front is much better.

Thanks for your examples. They've really helped, but the writer could have just said "allows you to put the initialization code at the top..." instead of "allows you to put the initializers," but they chose to use "allows you to put the initializers," and part of me believes that they did that for a reason and its that reason I can't figure out.

@NickParsons I just don't understand the reason for the emphasis on a section of the initialization code — the initializer.

"The wording of the text I'm confused by is as follows" - where is that text from? Please attribute your sources!

@Bergi JavaScript The definitive guide 7th edition

Don't think of it as initialization. What they're talking about is a way of declaring the properties of the class without initializing them (they default to undefined). You just do it by putting the property name in the default initialization section without assigning anything to it.

What's new in the syntax? The top of the class definition is gibberish. Where the class members are put is totally unrelated to the topic. At the time of constructor execution, those members are already assigned, even if they are written before the constructor. Isn't it even obvious?

Also, this is not a question. Nor did you not pose any problem. Is there anything to talk about at all? If you want to continue, please ask a question or explain if you need any kind of help.

Why do you quote some text without giving us the source of it? This way, you can quote any kind of stupidity and expect people to comment it. Why? And, by the way, the quoted test is stupid, as it says gibberish about “on top” and “advantage”. Advantage is only the stylistic flexibility, which is good, but not fundamental.

@SergeyAKryukov See previous comment. But yes, it should be [edit]ed into the question itself.

To start with, class is nothing but a syntactic sugar around constructors.
Both class forms shown in your code are equivalent to this constructor function:
function Buffer() {
    this.size = 0;
    this.capacity = 4096;
    this.buffer = new Uint8Array(this.capacity);
}

No matter where your defined properties are, they are created and assigned to not as a part of an implicitly created constructor of your class Buffer. Note that you don't have more than one constructor in your class, so no implicit constructor can be added to an existing constructor. Instead, your properties come as a part of an implicitly created constructor function, like the one shown above.
By the way, there is a common misconception that the properties created outside a class constructor have to be created only before the constructor. This is not true, it does not really matter — some properties can be created before, and some — after the constructor. This is only the textual order. Consider this:


const A = class { // note the const form,
                  // it helps to prevent re-assignment A = ...
                  // (yes, it is possible without const)
    a = 13;
    constructor (b) {
        this.b = b;
        // at this point, not only this.a
        // but this.c is already created and assigned to 14
        console.log(this.a, this.b, this.c);
    }
    c = 14;
};   
const a = new A(1);



In this aspect, there is no fundamental difference between property.this = inside a constructor body and property =  outside it. The common practice is to create in the class constructor only the properties depending on the constructor parameters. Apparently, they cannot be initialized outside the constructor body where the parameters are unknown. But this is not a rule, just a common practice — in principle, you can create all the class's instant properties in its constructor.
What sort of practice will make the code more readable and why? This is not a valid question. It depends on your coding style but even more on the semantic structure of your class. It even depends on the taste of the person reading the code. I don't think it makes sense to discuss it any longer.
Now, a few words about the terminology. The class entities you have created are not fields, they are instance properties. As to the term initialization, it usually refers to an object which is already created. In this sense, when you introduce your properties in the Buffer constructor, you do not necessarily initialize these properties, but your constructor performs the initialization of a Buffer instance. Indeed, a property can also be initialized, too, it can even have its own properties and a constructor, and it happens before the initialization of the class where they are created, but after the creation of the instance of the class, when its initialization is not yet complete.
